# Fastai installation via Conda fails with a 404 error

Tags: python, conda, fast-ai

I am trying to install `fastai` on my computer with `conda`, but I'm getting an error.

I am using `conda install -c fastchan fastai` and get:

> CondaHTTPError: HTTP 404 NOT FOUND for url
> https://conda.anaconda.org/fastchan/noarch/platformdirs-3.10.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0.conda

Is there something I need to fix on my end. It looks like it's a dead url, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 4):

To solve the issue, I have installed the platformdirs from conda-forge (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/platformdirs) instead of fastchan (https://anaconda.org/fastchan/platformdirs/files):

```bash
conda install --channel conda-forge platformdirs
```

After the installation of `platformdirs` was completed, I could successfully install `fastai`:

```bash
conda install -c fastchan fastai
```

Answer (score 1):

Conda is being used by the fastai library, but an error is occurring. However, it appears that the command you supplied (conda install -c fastchan fastai) is ineffective. Fastchan doesn't appear to be a valid channel for fastai, and the -c flag is used to specify the channel where Conda should search for packages.

You can use the following command to install fastai using Conda:

```
conda install -c pytorch -c fastai fastai
```

This command specifies both the pytorch and fastai channels to ensure that you're getting the correct dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting errors on the `fastchan` channel, and @Saurabh Dey's answer worked for me.

It is worth mentioning that you can also install fastai via [fastai's Github repo](https://github.com/fastai/fastai).  You need to have Pytorch installed.  Then install `fastcore` (a dependency):

```bash
git clone https://github.com/fastai/fastcore #Clone the fastcore repo
conda install fastcore -c fastai #Install fastcore
```

Then install a dev version of fastai.  This makes it easy to update the library later with `git pull`.

```bash
git clone https://github.com/fastai/fastai
pip install -e "fastai[dev]"
```